# Unable to maintain aspectratio - What's wrong in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

EDIT:
I'm not understanding the reason for not being able to maintain the aspect ratio of the drawn image. Can someone help to fix this?

I'm trying to upload an image and draw it using the imageDraw() and fit it within a 100px 100px canvas element.

html:

```
<div id="lbox">
<input type="file" id="uLo">
<div id="profilePic">
<canvas id="L1"></canvas><canvas id="L2"></canvas><canvas id="L3"></canvas><canvas id="L4"></canvas>
</div>
```

css:

```
#profilePic{
    width: 200px;
}
#L1, #L2, #L3, #L4{
    border: 1px solid;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

js

```
var counter = 0;
var canvas = document.getElementById('uLo');
var oPlaceholder = document.getElementById('profilePic');
canvas.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var originalCanvas = document.getElementById('L1');
function handleImage(e){
    counter++;
    var gEI_canvas = "L"+counter;
    var canvas = document.getElementById(gEI_canvas);
    var contx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            var imageAspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
            var canvasAspectRatio = canvas.width / canvas.height;
            var renderableHeight, renderableWidth, xStart, yStart;
            if(imageAspectRatio < canvasAspectRatio) {
                renderableHeight = canvas.height;
                renderableWidth = img.width * (renderableHeight / img.height);
                xStart = (canvas.width - renderableWidth) / 2;
                yStart = 0;
            } else if(imageAspectRatio > canvasAspectRatio) {
                renderableWidth = canvas.width
                renderableHeight = img.height * ((renderableWidth / img.width) / 2);
                xStart = 0;
                yStart = (canvas.height - renderableHeight) / 2;
            } else {
                renderableHeight = canvas.height;
                renderableWidth = canvas.width;
                xStart = 0;
                yStart = 0;
            }
            contx.drawImage(img, xStart, yStart, renderableWidth, renderableHeight);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't place a fiddlde link in a code block. Post your actual code in the question, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to calculate the sizing factor that will let drawImage fit the image in your 100x100 canvas:

```
// calculate the sizing factor that fits image in canvas
//  while maintaining aspect ratio

function scalePreserveAspectRatio(imgW,imgH,maxW,maxH){
    return(Math.min((maxW/imgW),(maxH/imgH)));
}

// usage:

var sizer=scalePreserveAspectRatio(w,h,canvas.width,canvas.height);

ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,w,h,0,0,w*sizer,h*sizer);
```

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="yourImage.png";
    function start(){

        canvas.width=100;
        canvas.height=100;

        var w=img.width;
        var h=img.height;

        var sizer=scalePreserveAspectRatio(w,h,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,w,h,0,0,w*sizer,h*sizer);

    }

    function scalePreserveAspectRatio(imgW,imgH,maxW,maxH){
        return(Math.min((maxW/imgW),(maxH/imgH)));
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks markE. I got the x y axis set and it's perfect.